# What's the term for a hole with a screw thread?

Tags: screws, fastener, terminology

I'm replicating a drawer handle that fits on an M4 screw. If you'd look inside the plastic hole, you can see a gold-colored metal tube that has screw threads. That's what the screw screws into.

[image]

My question is: What is the technical term for this metal tube? I want to order some of those.

Comment: [M4 threaded bushing](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/b4_bn1052/threaded-insertions/bossard/m4bn1052/?brutto=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIy-qOyveP3gIV07rACh0PCAQ0EAQYAyABEgKKDvD_BwE)

Comment: Possibly a pemnut there are a lot of different brands and styles.

Comment: Those are *machine* threads not *screw*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is simply called a **threaded insert**.    It is either first placed into the mold, then plastic injected,  or pressed in after the plastic handle is injected.   Google images for "threaded inserts for molding".

McMaster Carr or Fastenal if you want to buy some.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's mounted to something I'd probably go with (female) *threaded stud* or *insert*.